# Getting Runtime error while creating Telegram bot with Python

Tags: bots, telegram, captcha, python-telegram-bot

I am getting Runtime error while using pyTelegramBotCAPTCHA. I am using python-telegram-bot for this project.

My current code is this:

```
from telegram import Update
from telegram.ext import ApplicationBuilder, CommandHandler, ContextTypes
from pyTelegramBotCAPTCHA import CaptchaManager

group_id = GROUP_ID

bot = (
    ApplicationBuilder().token("TOKEN").build()
)
job_queue = bot.job_queue

captcha_manager = CaptchaManager(bot.bot.id, default_timeout=90)
captcha_manager.initialize()


async def hello(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    await update.message.reply_text(
        f"Hi {update.effective_user.first_name}! Hope you have a good day, to the moon "
    )


async def callback_daily(context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE):
    await context.bot.send_message(chat_id=group_id, text="One message every hour")


## * CAPTCHA START
# Message handler for new chat members
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def new_member(message):
    for new_user in message.new_chat_members:
        captcha_manager.restrict_chat_member(bot, message.chat.id, new_user.id)
        captcha_manager.send_new_captcha(bot, message.chat, new_user)


# Callback query handler
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda callback: True)
def on_callback(callback):
    captcha_manager.update_captcha(bot, callback)


# Handler for correct solved CAPTCHAs
@captcha_manager.on_captcha_correct
def on_correct(captcha):
    bot.send_message(captcha.chat.id, "Congrats! You solved the CAPTCHA!")
    captcha_manager.unrestrict_chat_member(bot, captcha.chat.id, captcha.user.id)
    captcha_manager.delete_captcha(bot, captcha)


# Handler for wrong solved CAPTCHAs
@captcha_manager.on_captcha_not_correct
def on_not_correct(captcha):
    if captcha.incorrect_digits == 1 and captcha.previous_tries < 2:
        captcha_manager.refresh_captcha(bot, captcha)
    else:
        bot.kick_chat_member(captcha.chat.id, captcha.user.id)
        bot.send_message(
            captcha.chat.id,
            f"{captcha.user.first_name} failed solving the CAPTCHA and was banned!",
        )
        captcha_manager.delete_captcha(bot, captcha)


# Handler for timed out CAPTCHAS
@captcha_manager.on_captcha_timeout
def on_timeout(captcha):
    bot.kick_chat_member(captcha.chat.id, captcha.user.id)
    bot.send_message(
        captcha.chat.id,
        f"{captcha.user.first_name} did not solve the CAPTCHA and was banned!",
    )
    captcha_manager.delete_captcha(bot, captcha)


## * CAPTCHA END

bot.add_handler(CommandHandler("hello", hello))

job_daily = job_queue.run_repeating(
    callback_daily, interval=3600, first=0
)  ## 9 hours = 32400 secs

bot.run_polling()
```

I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\user\Documents\GitHub\bc-project\tg-bot.py", line 17, in <module>
    captcha_manager = CaptchaManager(bot.bot.id, default_timeout=90)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 669, in id
    return self.bot.id
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\telegram\_bot.py", line 658, in bot
    raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: ExtBot is not properly initialized. Call `ExtBot.initialize` before accessing this property.
```

I tried to initialize the bot with initialize() function also I tried to use initialize() function for captcha_manager but it didn't work. Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Citing the [readme of `pyTelegramBotCAPTCHA`](https://pypi.org/project/pyTelegramBotCAPTCHA/)

> An easy to use and (hopefully useful) image CAPTCHA soltion for [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI).

This means that `pyTelegramBotCAPTCHA` is an extension for the `pyTelegramBotAPI` library and not for `python-telegram-bot`. All the examples in the readme are written with `pyTelegramBotAPI`. I can not judge if `pyTelegramBotCAPTCHA` is compatible with `python-telegram-bot`.

In any case, I strongly recommand that you choose *one* python library for the communication with Telegram (either `pyTelegramBotAPI` xor `python-telegram-bot`) and stick with that.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it seems that I did not read the docs carefully.